# Detect database DDL schema changes with Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

Let's say that we have a Django app that looks on a legacy database.
If someone make changes on some database tables from a db client as DBeaver for example and not through Django models, is there a way to identify these changes?

Comment: What do you mean with "identify these changes"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in a terminal, inside your Django project directory : python manage.py inspectdb > models.py

You will have models related to your tables.

By default, inspectdb creates unmanaged models. That is, managed = False in the model’s Meta class tells Django not to manage each table’s creation, modification, and deletion.

If you do want to allow Django to manage the table’s lifecycle, you’ll need to change the managed option above to True (or remove it because True is its default value).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, I am already aware of this solution, but I am just curious if there is a way to detect any changes automatically